# fancytree tr class persist

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I try setup different class for tr

this code work, but fancytree when i click to tr - select id add fancytree-active and when i unselect it fancy remove all css classes from tr and add defaults.

How i can persist tr color

```
$("#"+taskTreeId).fancytree({

extensions: ["dnd", "edit","table","persist"],
        checkbox: false,
        keyboard: false,
        table: {
            indentation: 20,      
            nodeColumnIdx: 2,     
            checkboxColumnIdx: 0  
        },
        renderColumns: function(event, data) {
            var node = data.node,
                $tdList = $(node.tr).find(">td");

            ...


        $tdList.parent('tr')
                .addClass(classAdd)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tr markup is updated every time the state changes, but  you could use the 'extraClasses' property to add custom classes that remain.